# How can I have different Emacs sessions loaded on different Emacs windows while using Emacs on daemon mode?

Tags: emacs

I'm currently using Emacs on daemon mode. I save my sessions using the [desktop](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Saving-Emacs-Sessions.html) package. I also combine that with [this](http://scottfrazersblog.blogspot.com/2009/12/emacs-named-desktop-sessions.html) in order to have several named sessions saved. If I have several Emacs windows open they all open up in the same session and if I switch to another session all the Emacs windows switch to the same session. I would like to be able to have different session in different Windows. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

from the emacs info documentation:

```
You can run multiple Emacs servers on the same machine by giving
each one a unique "server name", using the variable `server-name'.  For
example, `M-x set-variable <RET> server-name <RET> foo <RET>' sets the
server name to `foo'.  The `emacsclient' program can specify a server by
name, using the `-s' option.
```

Does this help?

Comment: It sure works for me.

Comment: Note: when you set the server-name, the new name must be in quotes.

Comment: It did not work for me at first. I thought I was running in server mode, it was behaving like it was, I used emacsclient to connect. But going to `customise emacs -> top level -> external -> server -> server mode` and switching it on, did the trick.